# Retornar o dia da semana em Javascript

Tags: javascript, html5

Tenho dois códigos para retornar o dia da semana, porém no primeiro retorna indefinido, e no segundo retorna o dia errado, por exemplo no dia 22/05/2016 retorna quarta, e o correto seria domingo.

Código 1:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input#dataR").blur(function(){
        var data = $("#dataR").val();
        var teste = new Date(data);
        var dia = teste.getDay();
        var semana = new Array(6);
        semana[0]='Domingo';
        semana[1]='Segunda-Feira';
        semana[2]='Terça-Feira';
        semana[3]='Quarta-Feira';
        semana[4]='Quinta-Feira';
        semana[5]='Sexta-Feira';
        semana[6]='Sábado';
        alert(semana[dia]);
    });
});
```

Código 2:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input#dataR").blur(function(){
        var data = $("#dataR").val();
        var arr = data.split("/");
        var teste = new Date(arr[0],arr[1],arr[2]);
        var dia = teste.getDay();
        var semana = new Array(6);
        semana[0]='Domingo';
        semana[1]='Segunda-Feira';
        semana[2]='Terça-Feira';
        semana[3]='Quarta-Feira';
        semana[4]='Quinta-Feira';
        semana[5]='Sexta-Feira';
        semana[6]='Sábado';
        alert(semana[dia]);
    });
});
```

Comment: No seu segundo caso, você está passando como parâmetros para o construtor do `Date` os valores de dia, mês, ano, mas a ordem é o contrário (ano, mês, dia). E note que em JS os meses começam a partir de 0 (0 = janeiro, 1 = fevereiro, ...)

Comment: @carlosfigueira vi agora o teu comentário depois de colocar a resposta. Basicamente a dizer o mesmo que tu. Na próxima podes colocar resposta logo :)

Comment: E só pra constar, não precisa desse array com os dias da semana, daria para fazer `data.toLocaleString('pt-BR', {weekday: 'long'})`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Criar objetos Date com strings como `'22/05/2016'` não é boa ideia. O melhor é como no teu outro exemplo com `.split('/')`.

O problema que te está a escapar aqui é que os meses em JavaScript começam em `0`. Ou seja janeiro é o mês `0`.

Repara ainda que o construtor `Date` recebe argumentos por esta ordem:

> Ano, Mês, Dia, Hora, Minuto, Segundo

Dito isso podes fazer o teu código assim:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var semana = ["Domingo", "Segunda-Feira", "Terça-Feira", "Quarta-Feira", "Quinta-Feira", "Sexta-Feira", "Sábado"];
    $("input#dataR").blur(function(){
        var data = this.value;
        var arr = data.split("/").reverse();
        var teste = new Date(arr[0], arr[1] - 1, arr[2]);
        var dia = teste.getDay();
        alert(semana[dia]);
    });
});
```

#### Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/nzcoxtar/

Comment: Isso mesmo cara, obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score -2):

No meu caso, eu consegui resolver assim:

```
const diaSemanaAtual = new Date().getDay();
```

Answer (score -3):

Pode fazer assim:

```
var diaSemana = ["Domingo", "Segunda", "Terça", "Quarta", "Quinta", "Sexta", "Sábado"]

function obterDiaSemana(value){
    let sp = value.split("-")
    let result = new Date(sp[0], sp[1] - 1, sp[2])
    let day = result.getDay()
    return diaSemana[day]
}

console.log(obterDiaSemana("2023-10-31"))
```

Comment: Para que fazer isso? Sabia que pode fazer assim `console.log((new Date()).toLocaleDateString("pt-BR", {weekday: "long"}));`

Answer (score -5):

com essa função aqui tu pega os dias da semana

```
export function getDaysOfWeek() {
  const daysOfWeek = Array.from({ length: 7 }, (_, i) => {
    const date = new Date()
    date.setDate(date.getDate() - date.getDay() + i)
    return date.toLocaleDateString('pt-BR', { weekday: 'long' })
  })

  return daysOfWeek
}
```